# Is $g\cdot U$ open for continuous group action and open $U$?

Tags: general-topology, group-actions

I think given a continuous group action on manifold $M$ and $U\subset M$ open we should have $g\cdot U$ open, but I don't see how to prove this.

Answer (score 0):

For each $g\in G$, the map $T_g(x)=gx$ is a homeomorphism $M\to M$ with inverse $T_{g^{-1}}$, so in particular is an open map.

Comment: Why is it a homeomorphism though? Not sure I quite see that.

Comment: $T_g$ is continuous, $T_g^{-1}$ is continuous, and the two are inverse maps because $T_{g^{-1}}(T_g(x))=g^{-1}(gx)=x$.

Comment: Oh right. Because the inverse map is also a group action... thank you.